# Which CMS system for a community based site?

Tags: cms, community

I am a grey-haired professional programmer, quiet conversant in PHP, MySql, HTL, CSS which means I can tweak things or code plugins if need be, but I’d like something off the shelf as far as possible.

I would prefer something free but can pay if it is not hideously expensive (actually, I started out thinking free only, until I found http://pligg.com/ which is dedicated to communities, but has plugins which cost about $10, and I might be willing to pay for convenience).

Before I found that, I was heavily in favour  of Drupal, but might be swayed by something dedicated to my needs or with many, many users or great support or a great deal of plug-ins.

Anyhoo, what am I trying to do?

A social site for ex-pats to help them adjust to their new country. Preparing to get there, legal/visa issues, employment opportunities, accommodation, shopping, plus social stuff.

The demographic is mainly girls in their 20s, so a social angle is important. Integration of FaceBook, Flikr & the like might be nice. What I am thinking of is
-   main content provided by me and a few moderators
-   a Wiki to which everyone can contribute 
-   forums for discussions
-   small ads/freebie
-   user registration (which may limit access to certain parts of the site)
-   groups of friends, with shared .. stuff (photos, discussion rooms, etc)
-   per user blog
-   per user photo album
-   mailing lists
-   I think you get the picture …. 9and can you suggest moe?)

As I said, I was originally set on Drupal, which also has some pre-configured distros, but I didn’t find one yet that really matches my needs. Then I saw Pligg, which looks good, but I might have to shell out $100 or $200 to get it the way I want it. And I still continue to search.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Maybe [BuddyPress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/buddypress/) for Wordpress is something for you. It's a social networking plugin, which may be combined with any other WP-plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal actually offers lots of community based modules and/or plugins:

**Drigg Solution**

Not sure if you looked at it but there is a drupal/pligg module, called [drigg](http://drupal.org/project/drigg), that tries to reproduce what pligg does.

Unfortunately, due to the lack of participation the module hasn't picked up speed. There isn't even a version for 7 yet.

If you're interested in participating there seems to be a thread about reviving development: http://drupal.org/node/528518

**Drupal Commons**

If you're not needing something like voting akin to pligg. You may want to check out the drupal commons distro.

From the [project page](http://drupal.org/project/commons):

> Commons is a ready-to-use solution for building either internal or
>   external communities. It provides a complete social business software
>   solution for organizations.
>
> Commons helps organize content into topic (organic) groups with
>   blog, discussion, document, wiki, and event content types. It also
>   allows users to create (user) relationships with each other in order
>   to follow each other's activities on a site. Authenticated users can
>   view a personalized dashboard containing content from all their
>   subscribed groups. Site owners can quickly and easily change the theme
>   (powered by Fusion from Top Notch Themes) to incorporate their own
>   branding. Plus many other features for community-building.

This module has been picked up at acquia, thus it is downloaded [directly from their site](http://network.acquia.com/downloads/drupal-commons)